# Node.js custom render building

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, locomotivejs

I'm building an API in node.js with express, and I would like to extend the basic res.send from ANY of the external route files before a response is sent, as to pre-format the response and append in additional data. How is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of middleware. See http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware

For example, these lines activate the CSRF middleware and then make the CSRF token available to templates and generate the CSRF cookie used by AngularJS:

```
.use(express.csrf())
.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.session._csrf);
  res.locals.csrftoken = req.session._csrf;
  next();
})
```

Comment: I don't understand how that's related.

Comment: Following my example, "pre-format the response" where I set a cookie and use res.locals to "append in additional data". This will then be available to all routes.